Could hydrogen be used as a cryosolvent?
I've been thinking, could there be life that could drink and live off of liquid hydrogen. I heard it could dissolve complex protein-like lipids from this site https://projectrho.com/public_html/rocket/aliens.php
If not, why couldn't it? If it could, what would it look like?

Hello @Cathy, welcome to [worldbuilding.se]. Please note that (a) you're allowed to ask one and only one question per post, (b) speculating on what any fictional creature might look like is opinion-based and cause to close questions, and (c) per the [help/on-topic], our goal is to help you build an imaginary world of your own creation, not to validate speculative science. We're happy to help you design creatures that drink liquid hydrogen! But proving that it can be a scientific reality is off-topic. Could you [edit] your question to clear all this up? Thanks!

At the temperatures at which liquid hydrogen exists, very few reactions can occur, because that temperature is very nearly absolute zero (around 33 K, or a little more than 20 K if under one atmosphere of pressure). Unicelled organisms can't complete their life cycles below 253 K, and that seems to be the soft limit for life as we know it.
It's not an issue of "life as we know it", just that even exotic biochemistries require a certain temperature minimum so that critical reactions can happen spontaneously, and at liquid hydrogen's temperature, not many reactions occur at all. Of course, you could always handwave an organism whose metabolism and biological processes run on those few reactions. Also keep in mind that, at those temperatures, virtually everything else is solid, so things like blood and stomach acid and whatnot that are liquid as we know them would work in a vastly different way, if they work at all. Plus, you would probably want a solid-state-based brain if you want intelligence - a brain that doesn't need chemical receptors and can use silicon/other semiconductors and electrical signals as purely as possible without relying on blood or chemical flow.
